# Extract encoded message in WAV file

Tags: audio, encoding, wav, decoding

I've got a .wav file with a **perfect square wave (PCM data with only "FF" or "00" bytes)** and I'm positive there is some kind of encoded message in it.

I've tried everything I could think of to extract the encoded message in the file. From steganography to several different encoding schemes like NRZ, Manchester, Differential Manchester and got nothing.

I'm three days into analysis of the file and driving mad by now.

**Can any of you think of some way (or software) that can perform any kind of analysis on uncompressed pcm data?**

*P.S.: **The decoding of the file is part of a quiz with various steps and that is the reason I would rather not post the file or ask for a direct answer.
I want to get there myself**, just needing someone pointing me in a new direction or fresh thoughts about the problem! :D*

Comment: Any chance that it's simple binary? 00 = 0, FF = 1, then convert to ASCII?

Answer (score 0):

In te meanwhile I got some invaluable help and figured out it was a tape from a zx spectrum in form of a .wav file.

So all it took was downloading some emulator and loading the tape (.wav file)!

But thank you so much for helping Mike! :D